# How to not redirect and display the error if the user enter invalid input

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect, invalidation

I'm new to PHP and I just want to make some form like a basic form. But I have trouble in the values entered by the user. For example if they enter a empty field it should not redirect or if in the email they didn't enter a correct format the form should not redirect. But in my case it always redirect even though the input is invalid. Can you help me out on how can I stop redirecting to another page if the value entered by the user is invalid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FG4</title>
</head>

<style>

.error {color: red}

</style>
<body>
    


<?php
        $fname = $lname = $fgender = $mail = $dob = $address = "";

        $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $genderErr = $mailErr = $dobErr = $addressErr = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

        if (empty($_GET["fname"])) {

            $fnameErr = "Please enter your first name.";

        } else {

            $fname = input($_GET["fname"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and space
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$fname)) {

            $fnameErr = "Please enter a valid name";

            }

        }

        if (empty($_GET["lname"])) {

            $lnameErr = "Please enter your last name.";

        } else {

            $lname = input($_GET["lname"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and space
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$lname)) {

            $lnameErr = "Please enter a valid name";

            }

        }

        if (empty($_GET["gender"])) {

            $genderErr = "Please select a gender.";

        } else{ 
            $gender = input($_GET["gender"]);
        }

        if (empty($_GET["mail"])) {

            $mailErr = "Please enter your email.";

        } else {

            $mail = input($_GET["mail"]);

            // check if email contain gmail.com or yahoo.com
            if (!preg_match("/@gmail.com|@yahoo.com/", $mail)) {

            $mailErr = "Please enter a valid email.";            

            }
        }

        if (empty($_GET["dob"])) {

            $dobErr = "Please select your date of birth.";

        } else{

            $lname = input($_GET["lname"]);
        }
        
        if (empty($_GET["address"])) {

        $addressErr = "Please enter your address.";

        } else {

        $address = input($_GET["address"]);

        // check if address contain the following characters
        if (!preg_match(" /#|[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]/ ",$address)) {

        $address = "Please enter a valid address";
            }

        }
        }

        function input($data) {

        $data = trim($data);

        $data = stripslashes($data);

        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

        return $data;

        }

?>

<form method="get" action="trial.php">  

        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Larst Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Email: <input type="text" name="mail">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $mailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $dobErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Address: <br><textarea type="text" name="address" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
```

Here is the other code where it just print the values entered by the user

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    // collect value of input field
    $fname = $_GET['fname']; 
    $lname = $_GET['lname']; 
    $gender = $_GET['gender']; 
    $mail = $_GET['mail']; 
    $dob = $_GET['dob']; 
    $address = $_GET['address']; 
       
    
echo "<h2> Final Output:</h2>";
echo "First Name :$fname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Last Name :$lname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Gender  :$gender";
echo "<br>";
echo "Email :$mail";
echo "<br>";
echo "Date of Birth :$dob";
echo "<br>";
echo "Address :$address";

}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tend to go overboard .. But I use `if (empty($_GET["fname"]) ||  $_GET["fname"] === null || $_GET["fname"] === '' ) {`

Comment: Your form sends a request to "trial.php". Is that the same file as where the PHP code you've shown is stored? If not, then submit your form to that script instead.

Comment: There is no redirection statement in your code (it only contains a submission to trial.php) -- or do you mean that jumping to "trial.php" is a redirection ?

Comment: I think OP might be mistaking the term "redirect" with "successfully submit" --  It seems OP is looking to "catch" validation .. Substitute that verbiage and read the question again.

Comment: @ADyson the name of the first file is trial2.php then the other one is trial.php

Comment: @KenLee yes my bad thats jumping not redirection

Comment: You should post your form to trial2.php then, if that's where your validation code is. Then, trial2.php can run the validation code, and if the data is valid it can issue a redirect command. If it's not, it can display the errors.

Comment: @Zak it didn't really solve it but still thanks for trying sir

Comment: For sure we can amend your code to do what you want, but if I were you I will either do the validation in the target page just as suggested by ADyson , or use javascript to do the validation on the client side.

Comment: ...but if you follow the latter, remember you must still also have server-side PHP validation _as well_, because client-side validation is easily bypassed by users if they so wish. Of course if this is just a very casual thing it might not matter, but for real usage the difference is significant.

Comment: @Zak Yes, that's definitely overboard. `empty()` checks for undefined, null, and empty strings, it's redundant to perform the extra tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want.

One of them is to use a hidden form and submit it only if there is no error found after the validation.

Hence the amended code (based on your original code) will be:

trial.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FG4</title>
</head>

<style>

.error {color: red}

</style>
<body>
    


<?php
        $fname = $lname = $fgender = $mail = $dob = $address = "";

        $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $genderErr = $mailErr = $dobErr = $addressErr = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

        if (empty($_GET["fname"])) {

            $fnameErr = "Please enter your first name.";

        } else {

            $fname = input($_GET["fname"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and space
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$fname)) {

            $fnameErr = "Please enter a valid name";

            }

        }

        if (empty($_GET["lname"])) {

            $lnameErr = "Please enter your last name.";

        } else {

            $lname = input($_GET["lname"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and space
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$lname)) {

            $lnameErr = "Please enter a valid name";

            }

        }

        if (empty($_GET["gender"])) {

            $genderErr = "Please select a gender.";

        } else{ 
            $gender = input($_GET["gender"]);
        }

        if (empty($_GET["mail"])) {

            $mailErr = "Please enter your email.";

        } else {

            $mail = input($_GET["mail"]);

            // check if email contain gmail.com or yahoo.com
            if (!preg_match("/@gmail.com|@yahoo.com/", $mail)) {

            $mailErr = "Please enter a valid email (only @gmail.com or @yahoo.com).";            

            }
        }

        if (empty($_GET["dob"])) {

            $dobErr = "Please select your date of birth.";

        } else{

            $lname = input($_GET["lname"]);
        }
        
        if (empty($_GET["address"])) {

        $addressErr = "Please enter your address.";

        } else {

        $address = input($_GET["address"]);

        // check if address contain the following characters
        if (!preg_match(" /#|[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]/ ",$address)) {

        $address = "Please enter a valid address";
            }

        }
        }

        function input($data) {

        $data = trim($data);

        $data = stripslashes($data);

        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

        return $data;

        }

?>

<form id="form_id" method="get"  action=#>  

        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_GET["fname"];?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Larst Name: <input type="text" name="lname"  value="<?php echo $_GET["lname"];?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" 
<?php if ($_GET["gender"]=="male") { echo " checked ";} ?>
        > Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"
<?php if ($_GET["gender"]=="female") { echo " checked ";} ?>
                > Female
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Email: <input type="text" name="mail" value="<?php echo $_GET["mail"];?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $mailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo $_GET["dob"];?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $dobErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Address: <br><textarea type="text" name="address" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $_GET["address"];?></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>




<?php 
if ($fnameErr=="" && $lnameErr==""  && $genderErr=="" && $mailErr==""  && $dobErr=="" && $addressErr=="") { ?>
<form id="form_id2" method=GET action="trial2.php">
<input type=hidden name="fname" value="<?php echo $_GET["fname"];?>">
<input type=hidden name="lname" value="<?php echo $_GET["lname"];?>">
<input type=hidden name="gender" value="<?php echo $_GET["gender"];?>">
<input type=hidden name="mail" value="<?php echo $_GET["mail"];?>">
<input type=hidden name="dob" value="<?php echo $_GET["dob"];?>">
<textarea name=address style="display:none;"><?php echo $_GET["address"];?></textarea>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("form_id2").submit();
</script>    

<?php } ?>
```

trial2.php

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    // collect value of input field
    $fname = $_GET['fname']; 
    $lname = $_GET['lname']; 
    $gender = $_GET['gender']; 
    $mail = $_GET['mail']; 
    $dob = $_GET['dob']; 
    $address = $_GET['address']; 
       
    
echo "<h2> Final Output:</h2>";
echo "First Name :$fname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Last Name :$lname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Gender  :$gender";
echo "<br>";
echo "Email :$mail";
echo "<br>";
echo "Date of Birth :$dob";
echo "<br>";
echo "Address :$address";

}
?>


</body>
</html>
```